# Selenium MoveByOffset working one time only

Tags: vb.net, selenium

I using VB.net working with selenium.This is my code

```
With New Actions(driver)
   .MoveByOffset(100, 100).Click().Build().Perform() 'This code working only       
End With

With New Actions(driver)
   .MoveByOffset(200, 100).Click().Build().Perform()            
End With

With New Actions(driver)
   .MoveByOffset(300, 100).Click().Build().Perform()            
End With
```

The code above just working for first block only, i was tried many way, if one block worked, the other block will not work anymore. I using this code for other site same type still working normally but there special site it is not work.

What should i do now :(

Comment: I've never used Selenium so I may be way off here but what if you only create one new `Actions` object and use it multiple times?

Comment: The code still not work as your suggest.